# Run java application from command line

Tags: java, command-line

I have an external jar file which have a package structure, and I can't run the app from command line like this:

```
java -jar example.jar
```

How do I run my jar file?

Comment: what did you mean by i can't what's wrong with this command?

Comment: That's like ringing the doctor and saying "Help, it hurts" and hanging up...

Comment: Is the command line location set to the location for where you run the command?

Comment: *"and I can't run the app from command line like this:"* - Why not?

Comment: Would you like to share a screen shot of the command line?

Comment: Is your jar a runable jar? If not you have to use `java -cp <classpath> example.jar <Mainclass>`

Comment: I have problem with installing VarScan.  I download the VarScan JAR file from SourceForge. Then, I can’t run VarScan from the command line: 

java -jar VarScan.jar

Comment: @b.sad Do you get an error message? If yes please add it to your question.

Answer (score 1):

The jre should know which class has the desired main class to run. This is usually found in the manifest file or should be told explicitly like:

```
java –cp /<path>/<jarname>.jar com.package.<public_class_having_main>
```

Comment: The jar mentioned above seems to be runnable: http://varscan.sourceforge.net/using-varscan.html. So we need more details about what is happening